# What is the meaning of "reached out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am listening to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGLj8AH7gbA). At 0:33, Lil Wayne says:

> We just reached out.

What does "reached out" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To reach out" is an idiom. It means to try to contact someone. It implies that you are making an effort to get a hold of someone, rather than waiting for them to contact you. It is used frequently in business, because it implies that the person "reaching out" is proactive. It is also used in everyday speech.

For example:

> We are looking for a beta-tester for the new version of our software. I need to reach out to a few clients who would be good testers to ask if they will try the new version.

or

> Aunt Selma was just diagnosed with cancer. I need to reach out to her to ask if I can help her with anything.

Comment: Would you say that it is necessary to actually reach the person in order to have _reached out?_  I would say no - that _reach out_ means _attempt to contact._  Perhaps the attempt was successful - perhaps not.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, Adam. Thank you for the comment. I will edit my answer to reflect what you've said.